# Fetch values in DROPDOWN from MySQL table without using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Database having region and country. Each Country is connected to a Region. For Example:

**Country--- Region**

Cambodia- South East Asia

Thailand - South East Asia

India -  Asia

Srilanka - Asia

Melbourne - Australia

I have a front end where I can select Region from a dropdown and I want related countries to show up in the next dropdown

My Current HTML Code is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Region:</label>
    <select name="region">
        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="country">
        <option value="South East Asia">South East Asia</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to have this option when I select a Region, only the countries listed under it should show up in the next dropdown. For example if I select South East Asia it should only show Cambodia and Thailand. If I select Asia, it should only show India and Sri Lanka.

Is there any way to do it without using AJAX?

Comment: On the same page? no there isn't any other easy way to do so. Why not AJAX? You can cause the page to reload with new value for region and pick it up in PHP to generate countries, but that will generate a new request for the page.

Comment: I had done it with ajax previously. But some other functions of the page are not working when I use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should load all countries and group them to separated dropdowns and make these dropdowns invisible.

Then, when some region will be selected - just show proper dropdown and hide other dropdowns. But you need different names for the dropdowns with countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it client-side with JS
(http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml). Although this would only work if you had all of the cities/regions loaded.